# extract a line from a text file beginning with given prefix

Tags: python

How to extract a line beginning with 70863 from a text file?

```py
prefix = "X-DSPAM-Confidence: "
num = 0 
count = 0

with open("foo.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
         if line.startswith(prefix):
             count += 1
             num += float(line.split().pop())
    print(num / count)
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and also explain how the code relates to the title of your question

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick:

```py
def retrieveLines(prefix: str) -> list:
    lines = []
    lenPrefix = len(prefix)
    with open("foo.txt") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line[:lenPrefix] == prefix:
                lines.append(line)
    return lines
```

What happens in this function is the following. You give your prefix as parameter, thus "70863". Then, it checks for each line the first `lenPrefix` characters, where `lenPrefix` is of course the length of your prefix (in this case 5). So it checks for each line the first 5 characters and if they match your prefix, they get appended to the list `lines`. Then you can do whatever you desire with it.

Quick sidenote: `line[:lenPrefix]` works even if the line has less characters than `lenPrefix`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I have to replace the "prefix" with "70863" in every line? Also the prefix varies: from 4 to 8. I did that , but id not extract the lines from the txt files . Sorry, I'm a beginner. Clould you send me a sample how this has to be done in the right way.

Comment: To retrieve the lines, you basically call the function with the prefix that you need. For example, `neededLines = retrieveLines('70863')` would suffice your OP. And like stated, length of the prefix doesn't matter. You can pass a prefix of any length to the function